# Why does background-color:inherit; work sporadically in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Chrome - Mac OS X Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvx3s915/

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
var MakePink = function(){
  $("#parent").css('background-color','pink')
  setTimeout(MakeGreen,500)
}

var MakeGreen = function(){
  $("#parent").css('background-color','green')
  setTimeout(MakeBlue,500)
}

var MakeBlue = function(){
  $("#parent").css('background-color','blue')
  setTimeout(MakePink,500)
}
setTimeout(MakePink,500)
```

---

```
#parent {
  background-color:blue;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}

#child {
  background-color:inherit;
  height:200px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Steps to replicate:

- View Fiddle
- Open Inspect Element (Developer Tools)
- Notice that child element is no longer in sync with parent background color
- This also works if the page has significant CPU usage.

**GIF Animation: http://s.david.gs/1gzSV**

Comment: Not seeing delay or sporadic changes in the parent versus the child. Always the same. How's your memory on your personal machine? That may be an issue. Tried this in the 4 major browsers, no problems inspecting with Dev tools either.

Comment: Using Macbook Pro - Retina. Also have this issue reported daily from clients on a major app (30k+ users) (No low memory or incredible device CPU usage.) (see gif http://s.david.gs/1gzSV )

Comment: trying to replicate, sorry. I will try on my macbook.